# How to handle XCUIApplication.keyboards.keys[String].tap() in a better way if .type() method does not work?

Tags: swift, xcuitest

I am working with `XCUITest` and I came across one problem that I can't really figure out quite yet.

If `typeText(text: String)` does not work (yes the field is in focus and I can type manually) I have to use `.keyboards.keys[String].tap()`.

Sure I can create a function that would pass the string to the `keys[]` and call each letter but how would I create a method that would take String as an argument then break it down into a character array and then convert each member of the array back to String and pass it to the `keys[]`.

I would really appreciate your help!

```
func type(letter: String){
    XCUIApplication.keyboards.keys[letter].tap()
}
```

This is my solution but I'd like to have a more clean and robust way to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Does this fit with what you were looking for? Found [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/strings/how-to-loop-through-letters-in-a-string).

```
func type(word: String{
    for char in str {
        XCUIApplication.keyboards.keys[String(char)].tap()
    }
}
```